# mod_python.publisher always gives content type 'text/plain'

Tags: python, content-type, mod-python

I've just set up mod python with apache and I'm trying to get a simple script to work, but  what happens is it publishes all my html as plain text when I load the page. I figured this is a problem with mod_python.publisher, The handler I set it too. I searched through the source of it and found the line where it differentiates between 'text/plain' and 'text/html' and it searches the last hundred characters of the file it's outputting for ' in my script, so I put it in, and then it still didn't work. I even tried commenting out some of the code so that publisher would set everything as 'text/html' but it still did the same thing when I refreshed the page. Maybe I've set up something wrong.

Heres my configuration in the httpd.conf

> < Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">
>   SetHandler mod_python
>   PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
>   PythonDebug On
>   < /Directory >

Comment: What's wrong with mod_wsgi?  What's wrong with a more complete web server framework like Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration looks okay: I've got a working mod_python.publisher script with essentially the same settings.

A few other thoughts:

- When you tried editing the publisher source code, did you restart your web server? It only loads Python libraries once, when the server is first started.
- Publisher's autodetection looks for a closing HTML tag: </html>. Is that what you added? (I can't see it in your question, but possibly it just got stripped out when you posted it.)
- If nothing else works, you can always set the content type explicitly. It's more code, but it's guaranteed to work consistently. Set the content_type field on your request to 'text/html'.

For example, if your script looks like this right now:

```
def index(req, an_arg='default'):
    return some_html
```

it would become:

```
def index(req, an_arg='default'):
    req.content_type = 'text/html'
    return some_html
```